# How to prevent oracle database Connection timeout issue without connection pooling

Tags: oracle, database-connection, etl, talend, connection-timeout

I need to read around 80k ids from oracle and should iterate on each id to again use the id to query against oracle to fetch that data for that particular id and process it. But when reading the 80k records and iterating it is giving me connection timeout. 
I m using talend 7.1, i do not have access to setup connection pooling. So kindly help me with this.

error:
 tDBInput_1 Closed Connection
[FATAL]: 
 - tDBInput_1 Closed Connection

11:31:12
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection

11:31:12
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.ensureOpen(OracleStatement.java:4114)

11:31:12
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.clearWarnings(OracleStatement.java:3122)

11:31:12
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareForNewResults(OracleStatement.java:3606)

11:31:12
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.endOfResultSet(OracleStatement.java:3724)

11:31:12
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.close(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:205)

11:31:12
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet.close(ForwardOnlyResultSet.java:56)

Thanks

Comment: i will be using aggregation later which is resulting in memory exception, so hence this way

Comment: If it is timing out, it is most likely because the connection isn't doing anything for too long. Oracle would not disconnect a session that was in the middle of a query. What actual error is being returned, and does the disconnect happen predictably at the same time with every execution?

Comment: when you say 'Oracle would not disconnect a session that was in the middle of a query', how about when its data extracted is being iterated, will it still keep the connection open?

Comment: the disconnect doesnt happen predictably at the same time with every execution. For my last two runs the connection got closed after 21 and 8 hours

Comment: @Darla I would recommend checking if your processing can be done in a single SQL statement.  I've encountered many scenarios where the processing can easily be done in SQL  or  in PL/SQL on the database side.   Also, who is disconnecting your session?  As a general rule, Oracle will not disconnect your session, but firewalls, etc may if thee are timeouts specified.  Also, sometimes the network fails during long sessions and that will cause problems.  You can also trap for the disconnect error and re-connect.

Comment: @RogerCornejo Thank you! I have earlier processed with a single SQL, which will actually process around 3lakh records and these records need to be aggregated, but my talend jvm memory is not sufficient to process this huge records, so i am sending a batch of ids for processing. Like you have mentioned, this is a very long session it takes days for processing. Can u pls suggest ho do i trap the disconnect error and handle it.

Comment: @Darla  It's been many years since I've programmed in Java (your error stack suggests you are programming in Java).  You just need to trap for the kind of exception you are getting then in the exception handler do the reconnect.  Some folks test their connection by sending a "select 'x' from dual"; that will error out of the connection is dead.

Comment: I am actually working in Talend which is programmed in java. Anyhow thank you so much @RogerCornejo. I will try that